# Cannot extract a private key from .p12

Tags: openssl, gost3410

I need to extract a private key from .p12 file encrypted using GOST algorithms, I'm using the command below:

```
openssl pkcs12 -engine gost -in GOSTKCNA_file.p12 -nodes -nocerts
```

I have already set up several environments (using docker) with different versions of `openssl` and gost engines, but whenever I type in the command, there is an error:

```
140221432510272:error:0609E09C:digital envelope routines:pkey_set_type:unsupported algorithm:crypto/evp/p_lib.c:210:
140221432510272:error:0606F076:digital envelope routines:EVP_PKCS82PKEY:unsupported private key algorithm:crypto/evp/evp_pkey.c:36:TYPE=1.2.398.3.10.1.1.1.1
```

I'm sure I installed everything correctly and configured `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` file.
Typing `openssl ciphers | tr ':' '\n' | grep GOST` in terminal shows:

```
GOST2012-GOST8912-GOST8912
GOST2001-GOST89-GOST89
```

The pkcs#12 is also correct, since we are using it in other services, what might be wrong?

Comment: Do you have the gost engine installed? you can check it running `openssl engine gost` it should print `(gost) Reference implementation of GOST engine`.

Comment: @LucasMartins yes, the engine is installed, I also overriden a /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf as suggested [here](https://gist.github.com/nook-ru/e697d4748085ab6d2a76b2ac037a76c0)

Comment: I'm not familiarized with the gost algorithms, but, the OID printed in the error, 1.2.398.3.10.1.1.1.1,  is related to the algorithm GOST2004-34310 , and looks like the engine supports only GOST2001 and 2012.

Comment: In https://forum-nag-ru.translate.goog/index.php?/topic/146668-openssl-i-gost-r-3411-94/&_x_tr_sl=ru&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=sc , someone suggested: "that in openssl-1.1.* support for gost has been cut. I had to install separately from here: https://github.com/gost-engine/engine"